# MYSQL Error Not unique table/alias SQL join table with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, mybatis

i try to update my table in databse Using INNER join, but it keep showing error
*I'm Using MYQSL 5.5*
here is my code in mapper

```
UPDATE room_availability INNER JOIN room_availability ON list_hotel.hotel_id = room_availability.hotel_id
    INNER JOIN room_price ON room_availability.hotel_id = room_price.hotel_id SET ${Room_type}_room = #{kamarBaru},room_date = #{booking_date}
    WHERE list_hotel.nama_hotel = #{hotel_name};
```

here  is the error

```
    ### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Not unique table/alias: 'room_availability'
### The error may involve Hotel.insertUpdateRoom-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: UPDATE room_availability INNER JOIN room_availability ON list_hotel.hotel_id = room_availability.hotel_id         INNER JOIN room_price ON room_availability.hotel_id = room_price.hotel_id SET deluxe_room = ?,room_date = ?         WHERE list_hotel.nama_hotel = ?;
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Not unique table/alias: 'room_availability'] with root cause
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Not unique table/alias: 'room_availability'
```

And here is my database Design in SQLYog
[image]

can someone tell me where did i do wrong here?

Comment: `UPDATE room_availability INNER JOIN room_availability` - you have to alias the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might work:

```
UPDATE room_availability 
SET ${Room_type}_room = #{kamarBaru},room_date = #{booking_date}
FROM room_availability
INNER JOIN list_hotel ON list_hotel.hotel_id = room_availability.hotel_id
INNER JOIN room_price ON room_availability.hotel_id = room_price.hotel_id 
WHERE list_hotel.nama_hotel = #{hotel_name};
```